# AWS Boto3 Failure to Upload File Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am facing an issue where I am trying to test my authentication to upload files into an S3 bucket. Currently I am getting an access denied issue, but I want to ensure that my configuration is working as expected. The way I understand this code to be working is that I am using the profile configuration 'PROFILE_CONFIG_1'. This means I am capturing the access_keys and secret keys with this configuration.

I am then simply taking my local file and attempting to place in the S3 container. My doubt is that I am able to use the S3 browser to actually place the file in the path as expected, but the code is telling me differently.

```
def upload_to_aws():
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='PROFILE_CONFIG_1')
    dev_s3_client = session.client('s3')    

    local_file = 'test.txt'

    bucket = 'myBucketName'

    filename = 'path/to/dir/'

    with open(local_file, 'rb') as f:
        dev_s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, filename) # Fails with error (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation
```

UPDATE: I have attempted to add a file with the AWS CLI and everything worked as expected. Only now am I seeing an Access Denied issue in the python code. I also simplified by code to something like this, and still see the error message.

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='PROFILE_CONFIG_1')
s3_client = session.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file('Path_To_File\\test.txt', 'myBucketName','test.txt')
```

Update 2 for John:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open("test_file.txt", "rb") as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, 'take-uat-ics', 'destination_path/test_file.txt')
```

Comment: When you tested with the AWS CLI, did you specify `--profile PROFILE_CONFIG_1`? The AWS CLI is just a Python program that uses boto3 with the same permissions as your Python program would have. Does it work if you use a default profile that has the necessary permissions (eg without using `Session()`)?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, I modified the aws_default_profile and set it to PROFILE_CONFIG_1. I then executed the code in the update2 above. This code returned an 'Unable to local credentials' error. Any ideas?

Comment: You're indicating the key of the uploaded S3 object incorrectly. It cannot be `path/to/dir/` or `/destination_path/test_file.txt`. It needs to be a valid S3 object key for example `dogs/small/poodle.png` or `destination_path/test_file.txt`.

Comment: Hi @jarmod I am not sure I follow. That was just an example path as I am really using something like 'file_path1/destination_path/test_file.txt'. Do you still see this as incorrect?

Comment: OK, then please at least make the example keys representative of what you are actually using. As posted, they won't work and you provided no hint that you knew they wouldn't work but that you had it under control.

Comment: @jarmod, Sorry for coming off incorrectly. I believe there was a bit of miscommunication. I took a look back to my original solution and realized that you were correct in stating that I could not have the preceding /. When I changed that line in my code, everything appears to be working correctly. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two related problems in your posted code with your target S3 object keys.

The 1st is the use of `path/to/dir/` as the target S3 object key. S3 copy doesn't work like regular Windows/Mac/Linux file copy where you would be able to copy a file to a folder using something equivalent to `cp file.txt /usr/mary/` that results in `/usr/mary/file.txt`. That doesn't work with S3 APIs. The target must be the S3 object's full key.

The 2nd problem is the use of leading forward slash in `/destination_path/test_file.txt`. S3 keys don't require, or allow, leading forward slash as an indicator of the root of the S3 bucket.

Valid S3 object keys neither start nor end in forward slash. Examples of valid S3 object keys are:

```
dogs/small/poodle.png
destination_path/test_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Jarmod for your continued support on this issue. I agree with your analysis and will be marking this as the answer. I was able to resolve the issues earlier this morning, and was in the middle of writing a thank you note to you. So thank you :)